# Eigenvalues of idempotent matrix of rank $r$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

In the proof for the following theorem in *Linear Models in Statistics, Render & Schaalje*

$\textbf{Theorem 5.5}$ Let y be distributed as $N_p\left({\mathbf{\mu}, \mathbf{\Sigma}}\right)$, let $\mathbf{A}$ be a symmetric matrix of constants of rank $r$, and let $\lambda = \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{\mu^TA\mu}$. Then $\mathbf{y^TAy}$ is $\chi^2(r, \lambda)$, if and only if $\mathbf{A\Sigma}$ is idempotent.

I am stuck at understanding why the following is true:

> Suppose $\mathbf{A\Sigma}$ is idempotent of rank $r$(rank of A); then r of the $\lambda_i$ (eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A\Sigma}$) are equal to 1, $p-r$ of $\lambda_i$ are equal to 0, ...

Here are two questions I would like answers to:

1. If $\mathbf{A}$ has rank $r$, so does $\mathbf{A\Sigma}$. Why?
2. How do we connect rank $r$ to the number of 0 and number of 1 eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A\Sigma}$?

I understand how for an idempotent matrix, eigenvalues can only be 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\rank}{\mathrm{rank}}$
$\newcommand{\Tr}{\mathrm{Tr}}$
$\newcommand{\real}{\mathbb{R}}$

It uses the following two simple facts in linear algebra:

1. If $\Sigma$ is invertible, then $\rank(A\Sigma) = \rank(A)$ for any matrix $A$ that is compatible with $\Sigma$.
2. Since you understand that the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ of an idempotent matrix $P \in \real^{n \times n}$ can only be $0$ and $1$, suppose $k$ of them are $1$, and the remaining $n - k$ of them are $0$. Then
   \begin{align*}
   k = \lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n = \Tr(P) = \rank(P) = r,
   \end{align*}
   where we used the fact that for an idempotent matrix $P$, its trace and rank are identical. Some proofs of this can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101512/proving-the-trace-of-an-idempotent-matrix-equals-the-rank-of-the-matrix).

Comment: Another useful fact is that for any square matrix A, the number of non-zero eigenvalues equals its rank, i.e. rank(A).